# Get asp.net button html

Tags: asp.net

I have mostly worked with MVC but now doung a project in asp.net. I can't figure out how to render an anchor button, link button or whatever from code behind in a block of text. This button will do postback.

Example: The following errors occured, Click Here.

How do you get the html of that button and append it to the text?

Comment: You don't, just add it to the ASPX/ASCX and toggle its `Visible` attribute if you need it to be optional. Rendering controls dynamically using anything but components is a world of pain.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

Comment: I can't use visible true or false here. These are lists created dynamically. So I have to create the libks this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button to placeholder, like this:

In markup, add this:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

In code, add this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "myButton";
    btn.Text = "Dynamic Button";
    btn.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(myButton_Click);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

And access the button's click event :

```
protected void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do whatever you need 
}
```

**NOTE:** You have to recreate all dynamically created controls after postback! In this example code to create the button is placed in Page_Load so that it will be recreated at each postback.